# How to separate the timezone and datetime from a string?

Tags: php, laravel, datetime

I have a string get from a text file name.

```
$string = "20181011000000GMT+0800"

// trying to convert it 
Carbon::createFromFormat('YmdHisTO', $string)->format...
```

It shows me this error.

> Unexpected data found. The timezone could not be found in the database
>   Data missing

How can i separate the datetime and timezone, if there's GMT+0800 end of the datetime string?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can parse that format with a slight change to the format string you're using:

```
$string = "20181011000000GMT+0800";
Carbon::createFromFormat('YmdHisT+', $string);
```

The `+` sign tells the parser to ignore everything after the first timezone identifier (**GMT**).  Strictly, it'll work without the `+` too, but I prefer to use it for clarity. Up to you though.

See https://3v4l.org/kDorn

Actually, testing this a bit more, I'm not sure the plus sign is that relevant. I think either of the timezone format characters (`T` and `O`) are simply swallowing all of the timezone information, rather than just their specific parts. DateTime's parser can be a bit of a minefield sometimes.

Comment: I noticed if using UTC, then it will shows The timezone could not be found in the database

Answer (score 2):

I would recommend using **strtotime()** it accepts every valid datetime format. See usage: https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php

```
$DateTimeString = "20181011000000GMT+0800";
$timestamp = strtotime($DateTimeString);
// trying to convert it
Carbon::createFromTimestamp($timestamp)->toDateTimeString();
```

Comment: The one and only answer that makes sense.

Comment: I tried, but when i am using UTC instead of GMT, the time will add 8 hours for UTC.

Comment: I'm not sure what you are trying to do. But to me this is as expected. Subtract 8 hours from 00:00:00 and you would get 16:00:00. Carbon operates in UTC on default. It seems normal to me, if you put in a GMT+0800 date in, that Carbon converts it to the right UTC time unless you specify Carbon to be operating in another timezone. Learn more about it here: https://carbon.nesbot.com/docs/#api-localization